# Cannot connect to Wifi iptables error

Tags: wi-fi, 8.1-oreo, iptables

Lately my Google Pixel 2 will not connect to my Homewifi.
It tries to connect all the time. Looking into the Log I get an iptables error:

```
05-06 10:03:56.253 1120-1355/? D/RecurrenceRule: Resolving using anchor 2018-05-06T10:03:56.252+02:00[Europe/Berlin]
05-06 10:03:56.255 1120-1355/? D/RecurrenceRule: Cycle 15 from 2018-04-13T00:00+02:00[Europe/Berlin] to 2018-05-13T00:00+02:00[Europe/Berlin]
05-06 10:03:56.256 689-3393/? W/IptablesRestoreController: iptables-restore process 25082 terminated status=256
05-06 10:03:56.256 689-3393/? E/IptablesRestoreController: iptables error:
    ------- COMMAND -------
    *mangle
    -D wakeupctrl_mangle_INPUT -i wlan0 -j NFLOG --nflog-prefix iface:wlan0 --nflog-group 3 --nflog-threshold 8 -m mark --mark 0x80000000/0x80000000 -m limit --limit 10/s
    COMMIT

    -------  ERROR -------
    ip6tables-restore: line 2 failed
    ----------------------
05-06 10:03:56.256 1120-1355/? D/NetworkStats: Resolving plan for NetworkTemplate: matchRule=MOBILE_ALL, subscriberId=262073..., matchSubscriberIds=[262073...]
05-06 10:03:56.256 689-3393/? E/WakeupController: Status[code: -1, msg: "Failed to execute iptables cmd: *mangle
    -D wakeupctrl_mangle_INPUT -i wlan0 -j NFLOG --nflog-prefix iface:wlan0 --nflog-group 3 --nflog-threshold 8 -m mark --mark 0x80000000/0x80000000 -m limit --limit 10/s
    COMMIT
    , out: "]
05-06 10:03:56.256 1120-1376/? E/ConnectivityService: Exception modifying wakeup packet monitoring: android.os.ServiceSpecificException: Failed to execute iptables cmd: *mangle
    -D wakeupctrl_mangle_INPUT -i wlan0 -j NFLOG --nflog-prefix iface:wlan0 --nflog-group 3 --nflog-threshold 8 -m mark --mark 0x80000000/0x80000000 -m limit --limit 10/s
    COMMIT
    , out:  (code -1)
```